# Application of Hensel's lemma to $\mathbb{Z}_3[[j]]$

Tags: number-theory, commutative-algebra, hensels-lemma, formal-completions

I am trying to use Hensel's lemma to find all the elements which have a square root in $R=\mathbb{Z}_3[[j]]$. We consider $f(x)=x^2-\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_ij^i$ a monic polynomial in $R[x]$. Looking at this polynomial modulo the ideal $(3,j)$, we get $\tilde{f}(x)=x^2-a_0$ over $\mathbb{F}_3[x]$. This breaks into linear factors if and only if $a_0 \equiv 1 \bmod 3$.

Assuming $a_0 \equiv 1 \bmod 3$, by Hensel's lemma we can lift these factors to $R[x]$. So the only elements that have square roots are power series whose constant terms is congruent to $1$ modulo $3$.

I am not sure if I am applying Hensel's lemma correctly here. Any references or answers which justify or contradict this argument as really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You say $R=\Bbb Z[[x]]$ and then talk about $R[x]$. This is a little confusing. When you say $x^2\in R[x]$, which $x$ is that?

Comment: The question is presumably: If $R = \mathbb{Z}_3[[j]]$, which elements $r \in R$ are squares? Your argument showing that if $r \equiv 1 \bmod (3,j)$ then $r$ is a square using Hensel's lemma is correct. But there's another polynomial mod$\mathfrak{m}$ which has roots, namely $x^2$. So you have to consider this case as well. For example, $r = 9$ is certainly a square. On the other hand, $r = 9 + j$ will not be a square. So the question is actually a little subtle. The key is to factor any element of $R$ into a polynomial times an element such that $a_0$ is a unit, see Weierstrass preparation.

Comment: @Arthur Thanks for pointing it out! I will edit the question now

Comment: @user994373 Thank you for pointing this out. I was primarily interested in the group of units so I had not thought about it!

Comment: $9+j$ has a square root in $\Bbb{Q}_3[[j]]$ and $\Bbb{Z}_3[[j/9]]$ but not in $\Bbb{Z}_3[[j]]$. The squares in $\Bbb{Q}_3[[j]]$ are $9^\Bbb{Z} (1+3\Bbb{Z}_3)j^{2\Bbb{Z}} (1+j\Bbb{Q}_3[[j]])$. It should be doable to find when a square root has its coefficients in $\Bbb{Z}_3$ or not.

Comment: @reuns Thanks a lot! Looking at the squares which are also units it seems to be the case that if some thing is a square then it is also a fourth power, eighth power and so on. Is that right? or am I missing something

Comment: Sure the units of $\Bbb{Z}_3[[j]]$ are $\pm (1+3\Bbb{Z}_3) (1+j\Bbb{Z_3}[[j]])$ and only the $+$ are squares as well as $2^n$-th powers for every $n$. The square root is given by the binomial series $(1+t)^{1/2}=\sum_{k\ge 0}{1/2\choose k} t^k$ whose coefficients are in $\Bbb{Z}_3$ (more concrete than Hensel lemma which is just telling that you can construct the coefficients recursively)